# Working with Lists in Google Sheets Macros

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, nested-lists, google-sheets-macros, google-apps-script-editor

I have a list that I would like to add elements to, while looping over a nested for loop for cell indexing/referencing. However, there does not appear to a method that I can utilize to insert elements into a list. See example:

```
var colors = range.getBackgrounds();
for (var i = 0; i < rangeHeight; i++)
   for (var j = 0; j < rangeWidth; j++)
      colors.add("#somecolorhash");
range.setBackgrounds(colors);
```

This would be how I would think to do it, however the IDE in `Recorded Macros` does not seem to have an insert, or equivalent method to apply to a list object. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

- If you log `range.getBackgrounds()`, you will see that it return you a 2D array of the form `[[#ffffff, #ffffff], [#ffffff, #ffffff]]` - not a list!
- To assign new values to `colors`, you need to address the single entries by their indices `colors[i][j]`.
- Mind that in order to `setBackgrounds` the color range `colors` needs to have the same dimesions like your range
- So, in your sample, you need to replace colors rather than adding new values (otherwise the `colors` range will become too big for the sheet range.

Sample 1:

```
function myFunction() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:B2");
  var colors = range.getBackgrounds();
  Logger.log(colors);
  var rangeHeight = colors.length;
  var rangeWidth = colors[0].length;
  for (var i = 0; i < rangeHeight; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < rangeWidth; j++){
      colors[i][j]="#000000";
    }
  }
  range.setBackgrounds(colors);
}
```

- Mind that it is important to use `{...}` within `for` loops, otherwise only the first subsequent line will be considered as part of the loop.
- If you want to assign the same color to the whole range, you can use `setBackground()` instead of `setBackgrounds()`.

Sample 2:

```
function myFunction2() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:B2");
  range.setBackground("#00ff00");
}
```